# search an array for substring in perl

Tags: arrays, regex, perl, substr

I have an array.  How can I search the array such that each array item matching substring `/DT|DATE|DTE/` 
should be converted to `char(array_data)`.

Before execution:

```
@word = qw{STA_DATA1 STA_DT STR_DATE TMP_DTE VAL1};
```

On Execution any array element having substing as `/DT|DATE|DTE/` should be converted and saved in new array as below

```
@converted_word = qw{STA_DATA1 char(STA_DT) char(STR_DATE) char(TMP_DTE) VAL1};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Chris Doyle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24888296/368630) showed you how to do this with [map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html). If you don't want to use `map`, you can do this with a regular `for` loop too:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
use feature qw(say);

my @wordsn= qw(STA_DATA1 STA_DT STR_DATE TMP_DTE VAL1);

my @converted_words = @words;

say Dumper \@words;
for my $word ( @converted_words ) {
    my $converted_word = @words;
    if ( $word =~ /DT|DATE|DTE/ ) {
        $converted_word = "char($word)";
    }
}
say Dumper \@converted_words;
```

When you use a `for` loop over an array, the element used in the loop is an alias to the element in the array itself. Thus, changing `$word` changes the element in the loop itself.

***UPDATED***: I updated this program because Chris pointed out that the  modified array is suppose to be in a new array. Easiest way is to copy the old array into the new array before modifying it. Of course, this is where [map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) works out nicely: With `map` Chris can update the array as it's being copied. Here, I have to copy the entire array into `@converted_words` and then go through the array again to convert each one.

I use `map` but I've found that many developers don't understand it. Unfortunately the Perldoc for map isn't that helpful.

Comment: The for loop will also work. However the question said **On Execution any array element having substing as DTorDATEorDTE should be converted and saved in new array as below**. so you should update the for loop to put the data into a new array rather than updating the data in the existing array.

Comment: You're right. Easiest way is to just copy the array to the new one and loop through the new one. That's where `map` comes in quite nicely (modify as you copy. The problem is that `map` can be very difficult to understand for some people. With a `for` loop, you have to be careful not touching the index item.

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this with the below code.

```
my @word = qw /STA_DATA1 STA_DT STR_DATE TMP_DTE VAL1/;
my @converted_word = map {/DT|DATE|DTE/ ? "char($_)" : $_} @word;
```

This will read each element of @word array and if the element contains DT or DATE or DTE it will wrap it with "char( )" and place it in the @converted_word array. otherwise it will just place the string as it is into the @converted_word array.

below code example to show it working.

```
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my @word = qw /STA_DATA1 STA_DT STR_DATE TMP_DTE VAL1/;
my @converted_word = map {/DT|DATE|DTE/ ? "char($_)" : $_} @word;


print Dumper(\@word,\@converted_word);
```

output

```
$VAR1 = [
           'STA_DATA1',
           'STA_DT',
           'STR_DATE',
           'TMP_DTE',
           'VAL1'
         ]; 
$VAR2 = [
           'STA_DATA1',
           'char(STA_DT)',
           'char(STR_DATE)',
           'char(TMP_DTE)',
           'VAL1'

     ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
map{s/$_/char\($_\)/ if /DT|DATE|DTE/} @word;
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid conversion of `STR_DTA` to `char(STR_DTA)` you could use:

```
my @word = qw /STA_DATA1 STA_DT STR_DATE STR_DTA TMP_DTE VAL1/;
my @converted_word = map {/_(?:DT|DATE|DTE)\b/ ? "char($_)" : $_} @word;
say Dumper\@converted_word;
```

**Output:**

```
$VAR1 = [
      'STA_DATA1',
      'char(STA_DT)',
      'char(STR_DATE)',
      'STR_DTA',
      'char(TMP_DTE)',
      'VAL1'
    ];
```